# Kendo UI JSON result to ASP.NET MVC5 Action as parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI Javascript - kendoGrid - (not the ASP.NET MVC) and ASP.NET MVC behind it.

I have a question:

Where do I run the **sync method** of the dataSource in kendo when

autoSync = false and batch = true.

The parameter in the Action method recognizes the JSON obj when autoSync = true.
It doesn't when it is set to false.

I tried to call it on the save event in kendoGrid but that did nothing. Thanks in advance for all the help :)

Here's what I've done:

ViewModel:

```
public class TaskControllerViewModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(TaskControllerViewModel model)
```

View:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({           
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetAllUsers","Task")",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Edit","Task")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                type:"POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Task")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                type:"POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function(data,type)
            {                     
                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false },
                        UserName: { type: "string" },
                        FirstName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" },
                        Address: { type: "string" },
                        IsActive: { type: "boolean" },
                        DateCreated: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,          
    });

    $("#allUsers").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:dataSource,
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
        { field: "UserName",title: "User Name" },
        { field: "FirstName",title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName",title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "Address",title: "Address" },
        { field: "IsActive",title: "Active" },
        { field: "DateCreated",title: "Join Date",format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" },
        { command: "edit" },
        { command: "destroy" }
        ],
        editable: {
            mode: "inline",
            update: true,
            destroy: true,
            confirmation: true
        },
        edit: function (event) {
            console.log("at edit event");

        },
        save: function(event)
        {
            console.log("at saveChanges event");
            dataSource.sync();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the pervious answer, was a little rash.  If you turn off autoSync, then any changes will not automatically trigger a call to the server.  Setting batch to true, only determines how the grid will send the changes.  I believe you must trigger the save event.  Such as in this example - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing where there is a save button.  I hope this is more of a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Enabling batch edit means your JSON objects will be passed as an array to the Controller. You have to change the parameter in your Controller Action to a List or anything IEnumerable perhaps.

Here is the code for my Sample, you just loop through each item:

Controller Action:

```
 public JsonResult Edit(List<TaskControllerViewModel> model)
    {
        foreach(var item in model)
        {
            var userToEdit = users.GetUser(item.Id);

            if(userToEdit != null)
            {
                userToEdit.Contact.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                userToEdit.Contact.LastName = item.LastName;
                userToEdit.Username = item.UserName;
                userToEdit.Contact.Address = item.Address;
                userToEdit.IsActive = item.IsActive;
            }
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(model);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TaskControllerViewModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({           
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetAllUsers","Task")",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Edit","Task")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                type:"POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Task")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                type:"POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function(data,type)
            {                     
                return kendo.stringify(data.models);              
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false },
                        UserName: { type: "string" },
                        FirstName: { type: "string" },
                        LastName: { type: "string" },
                        Address: { type: "string" },
                        IsActive: { type: "boolean" },
                        DateCreated: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,          
    });

    $("#allUsers").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:dataSource,
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
        { field: "UserName",title: "User Name" },
        { field: "FirstName",title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName",title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "Address",title: "Address" },
        { field: "IsActive",title: "Active" },
        { field: "DateCreated",title: "Join Date",format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" },
        { command: "destroy" }
        ],
        toolbar: ["save","cancel"],
        editable: {
            mode: "incell",
            update: true,
            destroy: true,
            confirmation:true
        },           
        edit: function (event) {
            console.log("at edit event");

        },
        save: function(event)
        {
            console.log("at saveChanges event");
        },        
    });
});
```

I hope this can help someone in the future.